# show multiple info-windows with ng-map in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I have this code for showing a info-window in google maps . The problem is that it always shows the same data in the info window. For the markers it is no problem to use the $scope.result array.

```
<div id="allesMap">
        <ng-map zoom="9" center="[51.2132822,4.4304089]" >

            <marker ng-repeat-start="x in result" position="{{x.point_lat}},{{x.point_lng}}" icon="images/wifi.png" on-click="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')">
                <info-window id="myInfoWindow">
                    <div class="infoWindowTekst"> gemeente: {{x.gemeente}}<br>
                        straat: {{x.straat}} {{x.huisnr}} <br>
                    </div>
                </info-window>
            </marker> 

            <marker ng-repeat-end ></marker>
        </ng-map> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From performance perspective it always a better option to create a *single* instance of info window and display information depending on the selected marker.   The following example demonstrates how to accomplish it:

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller('mapController', function($scope, NgMap) {

        NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
            $scope.map = map;
        });
        $scope.cities = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Oslo', pos: [59.923043, 10.752839] },
            { id: 2, name: 'Stockholm', pos: [59.339025, 18.065818] },
            { id: 3, name: 'Copenhagen', pos: [55.675507, 12.574227] },
            { id: 4, name: 'Berlin', pos: [52.521248, 13.399038] },
            { id: 5, name: 'Paris', pos: [48.856127, 2.346525] }
        ];
        $scope.showCity = function(event, city) {
            $scope.selectedCity = city;
            $scope.map.showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow', this);
        };

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapController">
    <ng-map default-style="true" zoom="5" center="59.339025, 18.065818">
        <info-window id="myInfoWindow">
            <div ng-non-bindable>
                <h4>{{selectedCity.name}}</h4>
            </div>
        </info-window>
        <marker ng-repeat="c in cities"
                position="{{c.pos}}" title="{{c.name}}" id="{{c.id}}" on-click="showCity(event, c)">
        </marker>
    </ng-map>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/7nqg7f7f/)

Comment: Thanks @Vadim Gremyachev