# ngMaps: InvalidValueError: setPlace: not an Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I'm customizing a google map with ngmaps (https://ngmap.github.io), google maps api and angularJS. What I want is to bring the marker of a place, look in the documentation of the api of google maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en) and there is an option that is call **"place"** that according to I understand is to put the ID of the place.
And when I load the web page it gives me this error in console **"InvalidValueError: setPlace: not an Object"**. I can't find anything like that.
My code it's:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngMap"]);
```

```html
<ng-map zoom="16" center="[-33.140981,-68.48775]">
    <marker
      place="ChIJycfzCxhdfpYRL"
      
      title="Cherry"
      position="[-33.140981,-68.48775]"
      z-index="1">
       
      </marker>
</ng-map>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDR3Q2Db6TbqNpXecvdHERFxK3RBRII9f8"></script>
```

If anyone can help me I thank you very much!

Sorry for my English!

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MarkerPlace object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MarkerPlace) `place` attribute accepts the following format:

```
{"placeId": "<placeid>","location": {"lat": <lat>, "lng":<lng>}, "query": "<query>"}
```

In your case `place` value could be specified like this:

```
<marker place="{'placeId': 'ChIJycfzCxhdfpYRL','location': {'lat': -33.140981, 'lng':-68.48775}}" title="Cherry" z-index="1"></marker>
```

Example

```js
angular.module('map-app', ['ngMap'])

    .controller('map-controller', ['NgMap',
        function (NgMap) {
           
        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div ng-app="map-app" ng-controller="map-controller">
  <ng-map center="-33.140981,-68.48775" zoom="4">
    <marker place="{'placeId': 'ChIJycfzCxhdfpYRL','location': {'lat': -33.140981, 'lng':-68.48775}}" title="Cherry" z-index="1"></marker>
  </ng-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @VadimGremyachev, thank you very much for your help! It served me a lot! I have a query more, I want to click to show data should use the directive "info-window" and to change the marker icon add to the "marker" tag the "icon" property? This is correct? Thank you so much for everything! Regards!

Comment: @Emily, [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34796581/1375553)  demonstrates how to utilize info-window directive